# Splitting polygon with turf.rectangleGrid in vue.js Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, turf, vue.js

The `turf.rectangleGrid` function from turf.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/rectangle-grid) makes rectangles inside a bbox, but I want them in a polygon.

The options take in a mask: Polygon not sure what to do maybe pass in a bboxPolygon?

```
 initNewPolygon() {
      let coords = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Polygon",
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  [
                    -8.184642791748047,
                    54.63688952465295
                  ],
                  [
                    -8.187904357910156,
                    54.63038157286219
                  ],
                  [
                    -8.178634643554688,
                    54.62665517743962
                  ],
                  [
                    -8.17159652709961,
                    54.63167331025528
                  ],
                  [
                    -8.176488876342773,
                    54.63534956905763
                  ],
                  [
                    -8.184642791748047,
                    54.63688952465295
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      };

      // bbox next to donegal
      let rectangleNew = L.geoJSON(coords).addTo(this.map);

      // bbox = min Longitude , min Latitude , max Longitude , max Latitude
      
      let bbox = [-8.184642791748046, 54.63038157286219, -8.178634643554688, 54.63167331025528]

      let cellWidth = 0.05;
      let cellHeight = 0.05;

      // let polygonn = turf.polygon([
      //             [
      //               -8.184642791748047,
      //               54.63688952465295
      //             ],
      //             [
      //               -8.187904357910156,
      //               54.63038157286219
      //             ],
      //             [
      //               -8.178634643554688,
      //               54.62665517743962
      //             ],
      //             [
      //               -8.17159652709961,
      //               54.63167331025528
      //             ],
      //             [
      //               -8.176488876342773,
      //               54.63534956905763
      //             ],
      //             [
      //               -8.184642791748047,
      //               54.63688952465295
      //             ]
      //           ]);

      // let options = { units: "kilometers", mask: polygonn};

      let options = { units: "kilometers"};

      let newRectangleGrid = rectangleGrid(
        bbox,
        cellWidth,
        cellHeight,
        options
      );

      let addToMap = [newRectangleGrid];

      L.geoJSON(addToMap).addTo(this.map);

    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to be step-by-step answer. `turf.squareGrid` method will be used for grid creation since `turf.rectangleGrid` is fairly new and I couldn't find corresponding `turf.min.js` library.

First bounding box is calculated for `coordinates` polygon with `turf.bbox` method. Corresponding layer is created just for visual representation:

```
let coordsLayer = L.geoJSON(coords).addTo(map);

let bbox = turf.bbox(coords);
let bboxLayer = L.geoJSON(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox)).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bboxLayer.getBounds());
```

This is the result:

[image]

Then grid is created, using computed `bbox` and  `coords` GeoJSON polygon:

```
let coordsLayer = L.geoJSON(coords).addTo(map);

let bbox = turf.bbox(coords);
let bboxLayer = L.geoJSON(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox)).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bboxLayer.getBounds());

let cellWidth = 0.05;
let cellHeight = 0.05;

let options = { units: "kilometers", mask: coords};
let squareGrid = turf.squareGrid(
  bbox,
  cellWidth,
  options
);

L.geoJSON(squareGrid).addTo(map);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Since grid from calculated `bbox` does not cover the polygon, obviously `bbox` has to be extended by the width of the grid, using `turf.buffer` method:

```
let coordsLayer = L.geoJSON(coords).addTo(map);

let bbox = turf.bbox(coords);
let bboxLayer = L.geoJSON(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox)).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bboxLayer.getBounds());

let cellWidth = 0.05;
let cellHeight = 0.05;

let bufferedBbox = turf.bbox(turf.buffer(coords, cellWidth, {units: 'kilometers'}));
let options = { units: "kilometers", mask: coords};
let squareGrid = turf.squareGrid(
  bufferedBbox,
  cellWidth,
  options
);

L.geoJSON(squareGrid).addTo(map);
```

This is the result:

[image]

What is left now is to cut off parts of grid that is outside of the polygon. This is done with the help of `turf.intersect` method, while iterating through all the square features/polygons of the grid (`bbox` display is left out now):

```
let coordsLayer = L.geoJSON(coords).addTo(map);

let bbox = turf.bbox(coords);

let cellWidth = 0.05;
let cellHeight = 0.05;

let bufferedBbox = turf.bbox(turf.buffer(coords, cellWidth, {units: 'kilometers'}));
let options = { units: "kilometers", mask: coords};
let squareGrid = turf.squareGrid(
  bufferedBbox,
  cellWidth,
  options
);

let clippedGridLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);
turf.featureEach(squareGrid, function (currentFeature, featureIndex) {
  let intersected = turf.intersect(coords.features[0], currentFeature);
  clippedGridLayer.addData(intersected);
});
map.fitBounds(clippedGridLayer.getBounds());
```

This is then the final result:

[image]

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/0dj4nqsb/

Comment: Hi thank you so much, this is what I was looking for, but the code does not want to work not sure it has consts that arent being used and cell height isn't being passed? any chance you could look at the code you gave me the final one and see if its 100%, thank you so much though!!!

Comment: cell height isnt used and once i copied the coee there is no squares on the polygon but its not throwing errors either dont know whats up at all

Comment: after step 2 when i put that code in it does not give me any rectangles inside

Comment: I added JSFiddle.

Comment: `turf.squareGrid` does not use cell height, since it deals with squares.

Comment: okay thanks, it still does not work in my code like it does in the fiddle, also is there any chance this can be done but only have 10 squares and somehow highlight each square on demand? so if the area is 30% complete 3 squares would be highlighted? so it would be based on a number 1-100, thanks so much

Comment: GIS SE site is intended for focused questions, which means one question per question. If you have additional question, please publish it as a new question.

Comment: If your code does not work, it means that there something wrong with it. Compare it with the JSFiddle code and check for differences.

Comment: Thank you so much, my new question is here if you could help i would really appreciate it! https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402892/highlighting-rectangles-in-a-filled-in-turf-polygon-in-leaflet-js-based-on-a-num